# Finding root of a function with two outputs specified in return statement

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am currently writing a code in Python where the objective is to find the root of the output of a function with respect to input variable x. The code looks like this:

```
def Compound_Correlation_Function(x):
        
    # Here comes a long part of the code...
        
    Equity_Solve = Tranches.loc[0, 'Par_Spread_bps'] - Market_Data.iloc[0,0]
    Mezzanine_Solve = Tranches.loc[1, 'Par_Spread_bps'] - Market_Data.iloc[1,0]
    
    return Equity_Solve, Mezzanine_Solve
    
Correlation_Value = optimize.root(Compound_Correlation_Function, x0 = 0.3)
```

As can be seen in the code block above, there are two outputs specified:

1. Equity_Solve
2. Mezzanine_Solve

I now want to find the root for both outputs separately. If I comment out the Mezzanine_Solve part in the return statement, then the the optimize procedure gives me the solution I want. Obviously, I want to automate my code as much as possible. Is it possible to specify the output for which I want to find the root in the optimize statement?

I tried the following, without success:

```
Correlation_Value = optimize.root(Compound_Correlation_Function[0], x0 = 0.3) 
Correlation_Value = optimize.root(Compound_Correlation_Function(x)[0], x0 = 0.3) 
Correlation_Value = optimize.root(Compound_Correlation_Function()[], x0 = 0.3)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your function returns a tuple of numbers, but `root` is expecting a single number.

Assuming you want to solve each equation separately, then you could include an argument in `Compound_Correlation_Function` to switch between the functions:

```
def Compound_Correlation_Function(x, return_equity=True):
        
    # Here comes a long part of the code...
        
    if return_equity:
        Equity_Solve = Tranches.loc[0, 'Par_Spread_bps'] - Market_Data.iloc[0,0]
        return Equity_Solve
    else:
        Mezzanine_Solve = Tranches.loc[1, 'Par_Spread_bps'] - Market_Data.iloc[1,0]
        return Mezzanine_Solve
```

Then pass the `return_equity` argument in as an extra argument via `args`, i.e. call

```
root(Compound_Correlation_Function, x0=0.3, args=(True,))
```

to solve `Equity_Solve`, and set `args=(False,)` to solve `Mezzanine_Solve`.

You could also define a function wrapper that calls `Compound_Correlation_Function` and returns only one of the values.

Answer (score 0):

surely you're overthinking it.  Just define two new functions:

```
def equity_solve(x):
    return Compound_Correlation_Function(x)[0]

def mezzanine_solve(x):
    return Compound_Correlation_Function(x)[1]
```